What was the fastest single engine plane with predominantly wood frame and fabric skin construction?
I've been doing some research and I haven't found a satisfying answer.
The Mosquito was quite fast but it was wood skinned and had two engines. The Bellanca Viking was fabric skinned but used a metal space frame for the main body.
A good candidate might be the Bell XP-77, a light weight interceptor built out of non-strategic materials in WW2. I've seen it quoted at 329 mph. (https://www.militaryfactory.com/aircraft/detail.php?aircraft_id=1248) Turns out the Bell XP-77 is wood skinned with some kind of fabric layer involved somewhere.
